# Python: Is there a simpler way to do this script?

Tags: python

I am trying to make self.id show exact value. I made it but I'm wondering how can I improve it?

```
self.id = 36

def OnClickNextPage(self):
    if self.id == 36:
        self.id = 37
    elif self.id == 37:
        self.id = 1020
    elif self.id == 1020:
        self.id = 2020
    elif self.id == 2020:
        self.id = 3019
    elif self.id == 3019:
        self.id = 5015
    elif self.id == 5015:
        self.id = 7019
    else:
        return

def OnClickPrevPage(self):
    if self.id == 36:
        return
    elif self.id == 37:
        self.id = 36
    elif self.id == 1020:
        self.id = 37
    elif self.id == 2020:
        self.id = 1020
    elif self.id == 3019:
        self.id = 2020
    elif self.id == 5015:
        self.id = 3019
    elif self.id == 7019:
        self.id = 5015
    else:
        return
```

I expect to get the exact value, but I'm not really sure how to make it smarter.

Comment: What is the purpose of ```id```?

Comment: I guess you could store the Next and Prev mappings in `dict` objects, but it wouldn't look much cleaner

Comment: @MichaelBianconi i use it for other function and i need the next value or previous one.

Comment: @CoryKramer hmm that is the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to shorten it, you can use lists for `self.id` values and the values you want to change it to. For the first function:

```
def OnClickNextPage(self):
    possible_ids = [36, 37, 1020, 2020, 3019, 5015]
    change_id = [37, 1020, 2020, 3019, 5015, 7019]
    if self.id in possible_ids:
        self.id = change_id[possible_ids.index(self.id)]
        return self
    else:
        return self
```

Make sure you return `self` so that it updates `self.id` for the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the IDs a list and keep track of which page (index) you're on instead. Make `id` a property so that you can easily calculate it based on the current index as needed:

```
class Pages:
    def __init__(self, ids):
        self.ids = ids
        self.index = 0

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.ids[self.index]

    def OnClickNextPage(self):
        self.index += 1

    def OnClickPrevPage(self):
        self.index -= 1

pages = Pages([36, 37, 1020, 2020, 3019, 5015])
print(pages.id)
pages.OnClickNextPage()
print(pages.id)
pages.OnClickNextPage()
print(pages.id)
pages.OnClickPrevPage()
print(pages.id)
```

This outputs:

```
36
37
1020
37
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an ordered list of the pages and then step to the n+1 or n-1 element of the list. The only complexity here is knowing where you are currently. If possible you could simply store n as well as id. If this isn't possible you could find n using the index method.

```
list_of_pages.index(id)
```

This isn't very fast, but it's less code to maintain.